# Checked List Box with data value property for each item?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Does anyone know of a control such as a Checked List Box where each item can have a value against it.

For example you have a list of fruits and in the listbox it displays Apple, Orange & Banana but the values for those items are A, O & B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CheckedListBox` control can already do that. Its `Items` collection accepts any object that derives from `System.Objects`. The objects are displayed in the list using the value returned from their `ToString` method.

Therefore, you can create your own custom classes and add them to the `CheckedListBox`. Make sure that you overload the `ToString` method to return the string you want to be displayed in the list box. Then, you can add any other methods or properties to the class that you want. When you get a reference to a selected item, you can cast it to your `Fruit` class and call any method you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is default functionality for .Net Listboxes, comboboxes etc.

If your Listbox has a datasource with items which have properties FruitName and FruitId you can set the DisplayMember to FruitName and the ValueMember to FruitId.

On selecting an item the SelectedValue will be the FruitId.

Answer (score -1):

What platform?  If it is HTML, then the `<select />` tag can have a different value and display string.

If you are working with Winforms, you can set the `ListBox` to have any type of object. so you could make a class that has a string for display and some kind of object for its value.  Then override the `ToString()` method and return the display string and there you go!

Comment: Check the tags. He's using WinForms.

Comment: he also has `.net`.  That's why I added both.  And I know that .net is also for desktops, but it frequently is used for web questions

Comment: Erm, WinForms is included with .NET. The question is tagged WinForms. That has nothing to do with the web. You have to read *all* of the tags to get the full picture.